# Does a 64-bit Integer PRACTICALLY have a limit?

Tags: mysql

I am developing a chat feature for my website.
In my MySQL database I use a 64bit signed integer for the `chat_id` attribute - which is an `autoincrement`.

So I am worried that once my system obtains a lot of traffic, the `chat_id` value could overflow.

So my question is does a 64bit integer practically overflow ?
And if so, is there a 128bit integer in MySql, JavaScript and PHP ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

64-bit signed has as highest value 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. It is extremely unlikely that the service you are building you will every have this many chat sessions. Not because I don't believe it will be popular once, but rather because this number is incredibly large.

To give an indication how large this number is (from Wikipedia):
In Java the time in milliseconds is a 64-bit signed integer. It will take 292 millions years to overflow...

So, no, you won't need more than a 64-bit signed integer for a unique chat_id, even more because you use an incrementer.

Answer (score 4):

The largest 64 bit unsigned integer is a staggering 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 - this is 18 quintillion, 446 quadrillion, 744 trillion, 73 billion, 709 million, 551 thousand and 615

If by chat ID you're referring to each unique chat started between two users you'd struggle to reach this amount even if you held the largest messaging service in the entire world.

If for some reason you believe you'd need a value greater than this, store it in a VARCHAR as a combination of digits and characters instead... e.g. 00-09, then 0a-0Z (really crude and won't actually be a good idea in this exact form but you get the point) etc going up systematically like that for as long as you like, that way if you need more space you can just increase the size of the field

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to being an ID value, no, its theoretical limit can not really be reached in practical usage for your scenario.

However, if you tried to store some randomly generated number in it instead, such as an UUID (which requires more than 64bit to store, but I've seen people trying to "speed it up" by downgrading it into a long number and store as such), then you could have matching values when you get to larger number of entries. Please notice this part about UUID, because most folks just observe how it looks theoretically improbable to have a match, then they pump dozens of millions of records within a month and find out that they start having collisions on a regular basis very often due to a way how collision chance rises dramatically as more and more of such "fake UUIDs" are generated.

**To sum it up - for your auto-increment, it's fine.** But don't try to "squeeze" a 128bit UUID into it and randomize it for some (future) migrations or something. "Hacks" often backfire.

Answer (score -1):

**EVERY** number in a computer has a limit. Every number is represented as a collection of binary digits. 64 bit operating systems can store numbers up to 64 bits. Numbers are infinite, computer storage is not.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34628550)

Comment: My answer to the question "Does a 64-bit Integer PRACTICALLY have a limit?" is : "YES"